# Get Shipping Methods via observer

Tags: shipping, event-observer, quote

What event do I need to observe to see what shipping methods are available for a given quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the "sales_quote_save_after" event, then use the quote to get the shipping rates. The following code can be used to get the list of shipping rates.

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();
```

Comment: thanks!, is there a way to add another code to be included in the quote

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of event.But i cannot find any proper event.

```
checkout_cart_save_after
sales_quote_collect_totals_after
sales_quote_collect_totals_after
```

etc

`checkout_cart_save_after and sales_quote_collect_totals_after` better because it trigger always whenever you  have done any changes.

but you get list of available shipping methods.then we need some code at observer

```
   $quoteShippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if (!is_null($quoteShippingAddress->getId())) {



        try {
            $quoteShippingAddress->collectShippingRates()->save();
            $groupedRates = $quoteShippingAddress->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

            $ratesResult = array();
            foreach ($groupedRates as $carrierCode => $rates ) {
                $carrierName = $carrierCode;
                if (!is_null(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title'))) {
                    $carrierName = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title');
                }

                foreach ($rates as $rate) {

                    $ratesResult[] =  $rate;

                }
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
             $e->getMessage();
        }
 }
         $ratesResult;
```

**Here $result give of shipping method**

Comment: @Amit this event is not calling, Whenever I am changing the address data like postcode, country, region.

Comment: What event used for getting shipping methods before place an order?